# left side of the material form input is not visible if requirement not met

Tags: css, angular, material-ui, angular-material

I'm currently creating the front-end of a webapplication using the material library. The problem I have is that when a field doesn't meet it's requirement. For example, you need to enter a 'bedrijfsnaam', so when you don't the border turns red. However when doing this the left side of the borde is not visible anymore. I've tried several things, but I just can't seem to find the right way to achieve this.

When the border doesn't have a color it is completely solid all around, the way it should be:
[image]

If an error occurs ('Bedrijfsnaam') isn't filled in, this happens:
[image]

So the left side falls off... I want the border to continue

html:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Component({
  selector: 'subscription-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./subscription-form.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './subscription-form.component.html',
})
export default class SubscriptionFormComponent {
}
```

```css
.subscriptionForm {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<form class="subscriptionForm" #form="ngForm"">
  <div class="textFields">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Naam</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" name="name" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Bedrijfsnaam</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" name="companyName" required />
</form>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You made your problem very clear with your description and the screenshots. But you need to provide the codes so that anyone can check and try to find a solution.

Comment: Good point, I've added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after breaking my head a few more hours, the solution I found was the following:

```
    ::ng-deep .mdc-text-field--invalid .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__leading {
      border-left-color: red !important;
      border-right-color: transparent !important;
      border-style: solid !important;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
      margin-right: -3px;
    }
```

But please if you have any ideas on how to make this better let me know